# Mapping text field to integer field in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I imported the data into my `Elasticsearch` and later on I was trying to change the field from `text` to `integer` but I'm getting an error:

> Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [include_type_name : false] [_doc : {properties={year={type=integer}}}]

My query:

```
PUT index-csv/_mapping
{
  "include_type_name": "false",
  "_doc": {
    "properties": {
      "year": {
        "type": "integer"
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

And error message:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [include_type_name : false] [_doc : {properties={year={type=integer}}}]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [include_type_name : false] [_doc : {properties={year={type=integer}}}]",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason" : "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [include_type_name : false] [_doc : {properties={year={type=integer}}}]"
    }
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

I'm a novice to `Elasticsearch`; how can I resolve this?

Comment: What version of ES are you using?

Comment: @Tushar Shahi I'm trying to run this on 7.13 but I have a production AWS instance with version 7.10

Answer (score 0):

Mapping types are [removed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html) in 7.0.0 and consequently, "include_type_name" is deprecated after 7.0.0.

Also, this should be the correct syntax.

```
PUT index-csv/_mapping
{
    "properties": {
      "year": {
        "type": "integer"
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get an error `illegal_argument_exception` reason `mapper [year] cannot be changed from type [text] to [integer]`

Comment: I guess that answers it for you. Type cannot change from text to integer. I also did not find anything regarding this in the docs. If you already have data you will have to reupload or if you don't you can simply make a new field.